# Entering Mexico as non-visa national by air, how do you fill FMM?

Tags: mexico, fmm-tourist-card

I was looking at the entry requirements for Mexico, and found out you needed to fill a *Forma Migratoria Múltiple (FMM)*

But I fail to find how, when entering by air

The governmental FMM [website](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html) only seems to allow you to fill it, if you are going to enter by land

And I don't really trust the shady websites like Mexico Tourist Card (link removed, they say they're official, but it's clearly not the case)

Can you fill the form in advance, or do you fill it solely on arrival?

Comment: might be worth removing the link to the dodgy website

Comment: from the Mexico Tourist Card website: "Is this the same Immigration Form I got on the plane the last time I went to Mexico?
Yes, it is exactly the same form. **You can wait and fill out the form on the plane** or, like most people now, fill out the form at home and bring it with you on your trip."

Answer (score 9):

In my experience they hand them out on the plane. There are also extras available in the airport immigration area. You could definitely fill one out in advance if you could find one somewhere, but there’s no need to.

Oh, pro tip: Unlike other countries’ landing declarations, Mexico has separate forms with English and Spanish instructions and headings (rather than having both languages on one form). If you do not yourself speak Spanish, make sure to grab the English one.

Comment: Definitely should be handed out on the plane

Comment: I can confirm this form has been available at all Mexican airports I have used as points of entry.  They are usually pretty visible at some kiosk and if not, an officer will gladly point to a nearby source.  It’s pretty trivial to fill.  It does look like the one on the shady website.

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2023, it appears that [Mexico is phasing out the FMM](https://www.mexperience.com/mexico-begins-to-phase-out-paper-versions-of-the-fmm/) and [no longer requires one for passengers arriving by air at its biggest airports](https://www.natvisa.com/mexico-blog/tourist-card-being-phased-out). (I was unable to find an official Mexican government source explaining this change but several third-party websites and discussion forums agree that it is happening, as does [the US government](https://mx.usembassy.gov/alert-changes-to-mexican-immigration-procedures/).) As such, they appear to have removed the ability for air passengers to fill out the FMM online which could previously be found on [the official website](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html).

If you arrive at a smaller airport that has not yet phased out the FMM, you will be given a paper form to fill out either on the airplane or in the arrivals area of the airport.